# Screen scraping gotchas

Tags: language-agnostic, screen-scraping

When screen-scraping, what are the "gotcha"s to look out for?

The inspiration for this is: my spouse's co-worker asked me to scrape all the pages from a Blogger-hosted blog that her friend with cancer kept in her final months and this lady wanted to keep all of the posts in case the blog were ever deleted. I eventually found a free tool that was barely good enough.

One issue with scraping many Blogger pages is that there's often a navigation menu where you can click on the triangles to expand the post lists by year or month. These little buggers created insane amounts of duplicate content because you'd have the same page over and over again with different combinations of the menus being expanded/collapsed. In Blogger's case I'm not sure this is avoidable since the links are all formatted as real http links and not obvious JavaScript calls. Still, it got me thinking:

If you were to scrape a website, what kinds of potentially non-obvious things would you compensate for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I screen scrape a lot. Some advice:

1. Emulate a [User-Agent string](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php) for some browser you want to use. Different websites frequently return very different results depending on what your user agent is. If they don't recognize the User-Agent they will often revert to lowest common denominator, so it's usually best to start with some recent browser. (For example the World of Warcraft Armory returns beautiful, easy to parse XML if it thinks you're a recent Firefox. If it doesn't know what you are it sends terrible HTML).
2. Be polite to the site you're scraping; don't hit it too hard. Your scraper will go faster if you multi-thread it, making many requests at once, but that will annoy the site owner.
3. Be smart about error handling. Do not write code like while (1) { makeRequest(); }. If your code or the server throws an error a loop like this will immediately fetch another request, generating another error. It can get ugly quickly. Handle errors well and consider putting in sleeps or exits if you see a lot of errors.
4. When developing your parsing code, test against a cached version rather than hitting the server every time. Will make your development go faster and is the basis of a simple test suite.

Answer (score 8):

### Do not use regex to scrape

While regular expressions can be good for a large variety of tasks, I find it usually falls short when parsing HTML DOM. The problem with HTML is that the structure of your document is so variable that it is hard to accurately (and by accurately I mean 100% success rate with no false positive) extract a tag.

What I recommend you do is use a DOM parser such as BeautifulSoup or equivalent (SimpleHTMLDom in PHP).

Some may think this is overkill, but in the end, it will be easier to maintain and also allows for more extensibility.

A regular expression could be devised to achieve the same goal but would be limited. For example, developing a regex to get the `src` and `alt` tag would force the `alt` attribute to be after the `src` or the opposite, and to overcome this limitation would add more complexity to the regular expression.

Also, consider the following. To properly match an `<img>` tag using regular expressions and to get only the `src` attribute (captured in group 2), you need the following regular expression:

```
<\s*?img\s+?[^>]*?\s*?src\s*?=\s*?(["'])((\\?+.)*?)\1[^>]*?>
```

And then again, the above can fail if:

- The attribute or tag name is in capital and the i modifier is not used.
- Quotes are not used around the `src` attribute.
- Another attribute then `src` uses the > character somewhere in their value.
- Some other reason I have not foreseen.

So again, simply don't use regular expressions to parse a dom document.

Answer (score 3):

First, I'd check for an RSS feed. On blogger, you just have to add `/rss` to the root url, if I remember correctly.

Then I'd check if there isn't already some tool to scrape blogger.

Then if there's no RSS feed, and no existing tool, I'd give up and do it by hand with copy/paste. Unless we're talking 5000 pages, it's much faster and easier that way. Take it from someone who's tried.

If you have access to the actual account, blogger has an export function.

edit: Or of course, you could try mechanical turk.

Answer (score 2):

As far as gotchas are concerned..It's usually a good idea to limit the amount of requests made over a certain period of time. Smashing a site with alot of requests in a short space of time is a good way to have your requests rejected.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the technical considerations, make sure your not putting yourself at legal risk.  Most large sites have specific legal language in their terms of use that disallows programmatic access to their services via an automated computer program, and also, the obvious copyright concerns.

From a technical standpoint, definitely use a DOM parser library and you'll save loads of time.  Many provide the ability to read HTML into an XML structure that can be queried using XPath to find exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you know someone who has access to the account, they can use [Blogger's export "Export blog" feature](http://www.google.com/support/blogger/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=97416).